# How to set an int value by recuparating a data in Java

Tags: java, android, string, mobile, int

I have a private void called initData() in which there are some datas ( logic lol), and in these datas there is a String which equals to a number. I would like to recuperate this number and attribute it to an int or anything I can use to do an

```
If anotherint != the number I want to recuperate  
{
  // execute the code
}
```

And I don't know how to do it ...

Here is an exemple of a data I use 
`list.add(new Exercise(R.drawable.jumpsquats, "Enchaîne un squat avec un saut.", "Squats Sautés", "3"));`
the String name of the number is set_number

I've recuperate the other values with 
`ex_name.setText(list.get(id).getName());`
So I did a getSet_number but don't know how can I use it

```
public String getSet_number() {
        return set_number;
    }

    public void setSet_number(String detail) {
        this.set_number = set_number;
    }
}
```

Here is the code modified with the help of @Christian Seiler

```
 int set_number = Integer.parseInt(list.get(ex_id).getSet_number());
                        if(actual_set < set_number)
                        {

                            showRestTime();
                            actual_set++;
                        }
                        else {

                            showRestTime();
                            ex_id++;
                            progressBar.setProgress(ex_id);
                            txtTimer.setText("");
                            String s = String.valueOf(actual_set);
                            list.get(ex_id).setSet_number(String.valueOf(0));


                        }
```

It worked by the help of @Christian Seiler! Huge thanks!

Thanks a lot,
Stéphane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the int value of your String, you max use 'Integer.parseInt​(set_number)'
Be aware that this method throws a 'NumberFormatException' if 'set_number' can not be parsed as an int.

Comment: int set_number = Integer.parseInt(list.get(id).getSet_number());  could that be correct ?

Comment: And how do we set an int to 0 after it please ?

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you mean, but
String s = String.valueOf(i);
where i is an int value; 
so list.get(id).setSet_number(String.valueOf(0)); should set your value to "0".